# Firebase: Convert array of objects into a true array on the front end - weird behavior

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am using `onSnapshot` to get data from Firebase to my front end. I'm trying to convert one field on the document, which is an array of objects, into a true array on the front end.

I already know that Firebase stores this data as an array of objects with each object's key as the index of the would-be array: 0, 1, 2, ...

However, on the front end, for display purposes, I was hoping I could actually convert this into an array I can map over. The data is a `userChat`s document for a chat app. See below:

```
{
  "conversationid": "someConvoId",
  "lastMessageCreatedAt": {
    "nanoseconds": 0,
    "seconds": 1598882400,
  },
  "lastMessageFromId": "someId",
  "lastMessageFromName": "Guy",
  "lastMessageText": "Hey, what up?",
  "readByUser": false,
  "usersArr": [
    {
      "userAvatar": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/65.jpg",
      "userId": "someId",
      "userName": "Guy",
    },
    {
      "userAvatar": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/60.jpg",
      "userId": "someOtherId",
      "userName": "Gal",
    },
  ],
}
```

The chat app uses group chat, so I'm using the `usersArray` to determine how many people are in the chat as well as display a user avatar, user name, and a "+1" (or +2, etc.) on the main Messages screen. In trying to convert the `usersArray` into a true array on the front end, I am getting unusual behavior. No matter what I try, methods that would work on either `Objects` or `Arrays` are rejected. `Object.keys()` only works for a `console.log`, but not when I try to assign the value to a variable.

```
const actuallyAnObject = chat.usersArray;
let realArray = actuallyAnObject.map((item, i) => item); // throws an error
console.log(Object.keys(actuallyAnObject); // displays in the console correctly
let keys = Object.keys(actuallyAnObject); // throws an error
let array = [];
Object.keys(actuallyAnObject).forEach((key) => { // throws an error
  array.push({[key]: actuallyAnObject[key]});
});
console.log("actuallyAnObject['0'] : ", actuallyAnObject["0"]); // displays correctly
console.log("typeof actuallyAnObject : ", typeof actuallyAnObject); // object
```

How can I actually convert this into a useable array?

Comment: Where does the chat variable come from? I’m not a firebase expert but the snapshot documentation indicates it has `docs` and `forEach()`, but is not actually an array. Can you use chat.usersArray.docs?

Comment: In the example data it’s `usersArr` but in your example code it’s `usersArray`. Is that just an oversight in the question?

Comment: Based on your code above, usersArray only contains hashes, so `usersArray[0]` should return all the values, and then you can iterate over those values to get key-pair for each user. So usersArray[0][0]["userAvatar"] would return the first avatar.

Comment: You need to show the code used for fetching the Firestore data.

Comment: Hi @Scott you can also try following the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52530006/how-to-turn-firestore-query-into-a-javascript-array). As explained in this similar case, you will have to better handle your promises, so your code wait for the data to be completely read and loaded, before trying to convert into an usual array.

Comment: @rayhatfield @kirill @renaud Tarnec @gso_gabriel The mistake was of course on my own end. I had manually entered data into Firebase, and in one document had the field `usersArray` and in another document had it as `usersArr`, without the `ay` at the end, thus the inconsistent behavior. Fixed now. Thanks for your help pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as Community Wiki, as it's based in the comments.

It seems that due to the fact that the data was manually added into Firebase, there was a difference between the name in the fields. While one was `usersArray` the other one was `usersArr`. This mistake was causing an inconsisten behavior while trying to load the data and convert it into a real usable array.